# Javascript - keep the button disabled on all pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function as below.

```
$("#update").click(function (){
             this.disabled = true;
            $("#kwBody > tr").each(function() {
               var $cells = $(this).children("td");

               var found=false,count=0,currentCell;
               for (var i=0;i<masterData.length;i++) {
                 currentCell=$cells.eq(i+1);
                 found = parseInt(currentCell.text(),10) >=masterData[i];
                 currentCell.toggleClass("found",found); //add or remove class to highlight 
                 count+=found;
               }
               window.console && console.log(masterData,count);
               $(this).toggle(count==masterData.length); // show if all cells >

            });
        });
});
$("slider:changed")
```

Once I click on the button for updating the values, I am trying to disable the button. However, since I am using pagination, if I navigate to the second page, my button re-enables again. Is there any way to keep it disabled across all the pages?

[This](http://omega.uta.edu/~rxv1100/willdoit.php) is the link to my work so far.

Comment: Thanks for commenting out. How do I set/unset the cookie to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use localStorage, or a cookie, to store the "true/false" value of the button. Check that value on every page load and assign its value back to the button's disabled property.

In your click handler, after "this.disabled = true", add:

```
localStorage.setItem("updateDisabled", true);
```

Then check for the value again on page load:

```
$(function () {
    var disabled = localStorage.getItem("updateDisabled");
    if (disabled) $('#update').attr('disabled', disabled);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting out. I am trying to add this line in the javascript function.   $.cookie("test", this.disabled = true);

But, the button is not disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do one of two things: (1) pass the variable back to your server in some way, or (2) pass it through to the next page.  You can do (1) with AJAX or a cookie, and you can do (2) with a URL parameter or a cookie.  The web is "stateless," meaning (among other things) that each page doesn't know anything about what just happened on another page, unless you pass that information along somehow.

Comment: Thanks for commenting out. I am trying to add this line in the javascript function.   $.cookie("test", this.disabled = true);

But, the button is not disabled.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do there.  `$.cookie("test", this.disabled = true);` will *set* `this.disabled` to `true`, then set a cookie based on the return value of that statement (i.e., the `test` cookie will always contain `true`).